# Google App Engine: How to make a "virtual directory"

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, bottle

I'm new with Google App Engine. At the first time using it, I was surprised since GAE doesn't allow me to write any file (including temporary one).

My Python application (based on bottle, http://bottlepy.org/) need to copy some static files from some different directories into a single directory with a single structure. I need to programmatically create a single directory as template path.

Here is my case:

The original directory structure:

```
/app
 |_ /views
     |-- base.tpl
     |-- /app_1
     |    |-- /models (this directory contains several files, we don't need to care of it)
     |    |-- /views
     |         |-- index_1.tpl
     |
     |-- /app_2
          |-- /views
               |-- index_2.tpl
```

I need to make a directory, let's say `.runtime/views/` and copy those original files into this structure:

```
/.runtime
 |_ /views
     |-- base.tpl
     |-- /app_1
     |    |-- index_1.tpl
     |
     |-- /app_2
          |-- index_2.tpl
```

Then I assign `TEMPLATE_PATH` variable into `.runtime/views`

```
TEMPLATE_PATH = '.runtime/views'
```

This approach usually works well, until I find that GAE has such a limitation (not allowing me to write any file or directory). I know they have reasons behind this, not to mention security issues. And they also provide some other solution such as datastore, blobstore, and even google cloud storage.

For me datastore & blobstore is not a solution since I need to make a directory. Datastore & blobstore is not created for this purpose.

Google cloud storage seems to be a good option. But it is a paid service (if I don't read it wrong). Also, I think I can't use this option since I need to develop things locally without any internet connection, then upload everything to deployment server.

Does anyone ever face such a similar problem? Any solution?

**PS:** Correct me if I'm wrong with some terms or concepts, as I said, I'm new to google app engine.

Comment: Is your requirement to create directories just once when you build you app?  Why would you need to create and move templates around at any point other than development?

Comment: @TimHoffman: I need to do that  whenever I make any changes (add, delete or modify) files on original `view` directory. Even on development environment (in my local machine) GAE doesn't allow me to do that.

Comment: Are you trying to build a through the web development environment.  If so then you will need to store the templates in the datastore.  I assume when you say files you mean templates.  If you mean content then that should be stored in the datastore.

Comment: @TimHoffman: Yes, The files are actually templates. Copying template content to datastore might be a good solution. However, doing that I will not able to use `%rebase` syntax (http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html). That `%rebase` syntax needs a valid physical file location.

Comment: Then you are out of luck.  You only other option is using google cloud storage, either way you will need to modify how bottle does stuff. I see a wealth of security issues down this path.